# Failure/Error when running rspec, no implicit conversion of String Into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I just setup a new rails app and the app itself is working fine, but when running
rspec The error below is returned. I can't figure out what is wrong here. Can anyone help? All tests were loaded from a composer base app and have not been changed.

```
$ rspec

An error occurred while loading rails_helper.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

TypeError:
  no implicit conversion of String into Hash
# ./config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Smarthost>'
# ./config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Application.rb: (Line 10 is the following: "class Application < Rails::Application")

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Smarthost
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec,
        fixtures: true,
        view_specs: false,
        helper_specs: false,
        routing_specs: false,
        controller_specs: false,
        request_specs: false
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot, dir: "spec/factories"
    end

    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

Running a full trace with rake --trace returns the following which points to an error in figaro. I haven't touched any of those files though. Any thoughts on what the problem could be?

```
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Hash
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:32:in `merge'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:32:in `configuration'/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:42:in `each'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:36:in `load'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro.rb:23:in `load'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/rails/railtie.rb:5:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:95:in `inherited'
/mnt/c/Users/chave/Documents/apps/smarthost/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Smarthost>'
/mnt/c/Users/chave/Documents/apps/smarthost/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/mnt/c/Users/chave/Documents/apps/smarthost/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/achaves/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: posting your `application.rb` file will be helpful if you look at the logs it seems like there is an error at line 10 in `application.rb`

Comment: application.rb  edited above). I've been looking that for the last hour and can't figure out what's wrong there. My other rails apps look exactly the same and work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by reinstalling figaro and then copying the old contents of application.yml to the newly created file after running:

```
bundle exec figaro install
```

Comment: There is something about figaro that causes this error to keep happening. The steps below do solve it every time. To confirm it's figaro run rake --trace